# org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.ReactiveNeo4jRepository save operation perform merge cascade relationship

Tags: neo4j, spring-webflux, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using following components:

1. Neo4jReactiveRepository
2. Spring WEbFlux
3. Neo4j

Steps taken:

1. Created Node B and C.
2. B node having outgoing relationship "xyz" with C.
3. When create node of B, need to pass reference of C like

   ```
      neo4jReactiveRepository.save(new B(C));
   ```
4. Now create a node A which having "pqr" relationship with B. So node A will be create as -

   ```
     neo4jReactiveRepository.save(new A(B));
   ```
5. Final flow will be look like in neo4j database is  A -> B -> C with "pqr" relationship between A & B, "xyz" relationship between B & C

Problem: At step no. 4, when create node A with relationship with B, it also update relationship between B & C.

I don't want to update relationship between B & C. I want only node A will be create along with relationship between A & B.

Any help will be appreciated.

Tried set null object of C during create node A, but it is removing relationship between B & C

Writing manual queries will resolve my problem, but I need to execute 2 queries:

1. Create node A
2. Create relationship between A & B

Code:

```
Create interface of ReactiveNeo4jRepository
    
public interface DemoRepository extends ReactiveNeo4jRepository<A, String> {
}

Service Class
    
class DemoService{
    @Autowired
    DemoRepository demoRepository;

    public void saveObjectA(B b){
        demoRepository.save(new A(b));
    }
}


POJO of A class
    
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Node("A")
public class A {
    @Relationship(type = "EXECUTES", direction = OUTGOING)
    private B b;

    public A(B b){
        this.b = b; = JobStatus.STARTING;
    }
}


POJO of class B
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Node("B")
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class B {
    @Relationship(type = "SUPPORTS", direction = OUTGOING)
    private C c;

}


POJO of class C
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Node("C")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class C {
    private final String name;
}
```

Comment: What does "merge cascade" mean, and how was the B/C relationship updated? Also, can you share relevant code?

Comment: merge cascade: Final node with relation as A -EXECUTES->B -SUPPORTS -> C
In neo4j database B -SUPPORTS -> C already exist. When we create  A -EXECUTES->B, internally neo4j reactive repository merges relation between B & C that we don't want to do.

Comment: Why we don't want to merge relation between B & C during create Node A?
Getting deadlock if multiple threads create Node A simultaneously.

Comment: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: ForsetiClient[transactionId=4465, clientId=1] can't acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[transactionId=4466, clientId=6]} on NODE(8), because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[transactionId=4465, clientId=1].
 Wait list:ExclusiveLock[

Comment: Client[4466] waits for [ForsetiClient[transactionId=4465, clientId=1],ForsetiClient[transactionId=4464, clientId=4]]]; Error code 'Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected'; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.TransientException: ForsetiClient[transactionId=4465, clientId=1] can't acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[transactionId=4466, clientId=6]} on NODE(8), because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[transactionId=4465, clientId=1].
 Wait list:ExclusiveLock[

Answer (score 0):

If steps 3 and 4 happen concurrently, that would cause deadlocks, since they both need to lock B. Whenever you create a new relationship, both of its end nodes also have to be locked (since they have to be updated to reference the new relationship). See the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/locks-deadlocks/#_deadlocks) some for more details.

Changing to only doing one step at a time should avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Step 3 is independent. 5 mins gap between step 3 & 4.  I just shown how A,B & C nodes are related.
Issue occur during performing step 4.

Comment: So are you doing step 4 concurrently? If so, you still have to make sure you never concurrently create multiple relationships involving the same node.